# Material Design Components Toggle effect not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-design

Im trying to use material components IconButton with React.
Material Design : https://material-components.github.io/material-components-web-catalog/#/component/icon-button

It work and show element and do repple. But toggle doesnt work.
here is my code and element tree in devtool for chrome.
please teach me the solution.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { MDCIconButtonToggle } from '@material/icon-button';

const ButtonLike = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    const iconToggle = new MDCIconButtonToggle(
      document.querySelector('.mdc-icon-button'),
    );
    iconToggle.on = true;
  });
  return (
    <button
      id="add-to-favorites"
      className="mdc-icon-button mdc-icon-button--on"
      aria-label="Add to favorites"
      aria-pressed="false"
    >
      <i className="material-icons mdc-icon-button__icon mdc-icon-button__icon--on">favorite</i>
      <i className="material-icons mdc-icon-button__icon">favorite_border</i>
    </button>
  );
};

export default ButtonLike;
```

element tree

```
<button id="add-to-favorites" class="mdc-icon-button mdc-icon-button--on" aria-label="Add to favorites" aria-pressed="false">
  <i class="material-icons mdc-icon-button__icon mdc-icon-button__icon--on">
    favorite
  </i>
  <i class="material-icons mdc-icon-button__icon">
    favorite_border
  </i>
</button>
```

Comment: How does it not work? Does it stay "on" or what?

Comment: Thanks  for question, hackape.  
in this case, its stayed on.
because "iconToggle.on" value set "true".
if it change to "false", it stayed off.

Comment: "Off" means show  "favorite_border" icon. when click that icon, ripple efect works. I have not written but also add scss modules. and it seems work well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You instantiate `iconToggle` inside `useEffect()`, but you overlooked the fact that `useEffect()` takes a 2nd argument, the [deps list](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect). Without it, that logic is re-run at every re-render, meaning your `iconToggle.on` is set back to `true` each time, thus it stays at "on".

As side note, a more React-ish way to select HTML element is by `useRef()`, instead of `document.querySelector()` which might find other unwanted element

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';
import { MDCIconButtonToggle } from '@material/icon-button';

const ButtonLike = () => {
  const buttonRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const iconToggle = new MDCIconButtonToggle(buttonRef.current);
    iconToggle.on = true;
  }, []);  // <-- You need to pass in an empty array
           //     to signal that you want this logic to run only once.

  return (
    <button
      ref={buttonRef}
      id="add-to-favorites"
      className="mdc-icon-button mdc-icon-button--on"
      aria-label="Add to favorites"
      aria-pressed="false"
    >
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! I changed script and try it, but result is not changed. There is no errors from first script. Are there any other problems?

Comment: Yes I will. I am beginner on programming, so I will post later after searched what codesandbox is. Thanks to your great help hackape.

Comment: @MIsoku I created one for you, [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wandering-bash-8w1ii?file=/src/App.js) I'm not sure what's happening on your side, but my code works.

Comment: GRAT! I saw your script works on sandbox. I appreciate it! I will try to make clear what different in my script.

Comment: For now, I could create sandbox and code [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/little-river-7m0yc?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)  I will post what the point of this problem, after I could find out different between two codes.

Comment: I really apreciate to your Great Answer, hackape.

Comment: I found out what problem was. I have used this component in top-app-bar component. 
and "top-app-bar" component does not have magic caractors',[]);' neither. 
so it caused same problem as you pointed out. 
I dont know well about stack over flow, If This text might be placed other space, please lead me.

Comment: It’s fine, comment is the right place. Glad the problem is resolved.